# How to set xticks in subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

If I plot a single `imshow` plot I can use

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(data)
plt.xticks( [4, 14, 24],  [5, 15, 25] )
```

to replace my xtick labels.

Now, I am plotting 12 `imshow` plots using

```
f, axarr = plt.subplots(4, 3)
axarr[i, j].imshow(data)
```

How can I change my xticks just for one of these subplots? I can only access the axes of the subplots with `axarr[i, j]`. How can I access `plt` just for one particular subplot?

Answer (score 216, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. Use the axes methods of the subplot object (e.g. `ax.set_xticks` and `ax.set_xticklabels`) or
2. Use `plt.sca` to set the current axes for the pyplot state machine (i.e. the `plt` interface).

As an example (this also illustrates using `setp` to change the properties of all of the subplots):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=4)

# Set the ticks and ticklabels for all axes
plt.setp(axes, xticks=[0.1, 0.5, 0.9], xticklabels=['a', 'b', 'c'],
        yticks=[1, 2, 3])

# Use the pyplot interface to change just one subplot...
plt.sca(axes[1, 1])
plt.xticks(range(3), ['A', 'Big', 'Cat'], color='red')

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: What version are you using?  I'm getting `AttributeError: Unknown property xtickslabels` for `plt.setp(ax, xtickslabels=xticks)`

Answer (score 49):

See the (quite) recent [answer](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/12318) on the matplotlib repository, in which the following solution is suggested:

- If you want to set the xticklabels:

  ```
  ax.set_xticks([1,4,5]) 
  ax.set_xticklabels([1,4,5], fontsize=12)
  ```
- If you want to only increase the fontsize of the xticklabels, using the default values and locations (which is something I personally often need and find very handy):

  ```
  ax.tick_params(axis="x", labelsize=12)
  ```
- To do it all at once:

  ```
  plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), fontsize=12, fontweight="bold", 
           horizontalalignment="left")`
  ```