# Change Number Formatting on X-Axis Matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I'm sure this is an easy answer, but could not find anywhere. I want the x-axis to read with the values 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, not 2 x e**3.

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004]
y = [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004] 

plt.xticks(np.arange(min(x), max(x)+1, 1.0)) 
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

The code returns a graph that represents the values like this. How do I change it?

[image]

@ avinash pandey

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]
You can use

```
plt.xticks(np.arange(min(x), max(x)+1, 1.0), x)
```

Try this as in your code space was already there just labels were needed...
For more follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19626530/python-xticks-in-subplots)

Comment: For some reason adding this line makes the x-axis disappear, although it moves some tick marks opposite the y-axis.

Comment: Picture is in the question above