# how to put ticks in subplots

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, subplot

I want to place ticks in required position in 1*2 subplot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
fig, ax = plt.subplots[]
n_rows = 1
n_colums = 2
n_plots = n_rows * n_cols
fig, ax = plt.subplots(n_rows, n_cols,figsize=(10,5), sharex = False, sharey = False)
ticks_pos = np.array([0.80,0.85,0.863,0.875,0.90,0.95,1])
my_ticks=[0.80,0.85,'r1','r2',0.90,0.95,1]
ax[0].set_xticks(ticks_pos,my_ticks)
plt.show()
```

This is not working. Please help.

Comment: `.set_xticks(ticks_pos)`, `.set_xticklabels(my_ticks)`

Comment: You may also want to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19626530/python-xticks-in-subplots