# How to show xtickslabel for each subplots

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, subplot

I m sharing this image for dff sample. [dff sample ][1]
I'm using code below to create 11x12 grid subplots and I want to show `xtickslabel` for each subplot. But it's not successful.

I tried to add `visible=True` or putting codes after plotting but it did not work.

```
xlabelss=dff['DATE'].unique()
xtickss=list(range(0, len(xlabelss)))
plt.figure(figsize=(200,250), facecolor='white')
plot_number = 1
for rname in dff['REGION'].unique():
    for cname in dff['CONF'].unique():                  
        if dff.loc[(dff['REGION'] == rname) &(dff['CONF'] == cname)].agg({'CELL': np.sum}).all()==0:
            plot_number = plot_number + 1
        if dff.loc[(dff['REGION'] == rname) &(dff['CONF'] == cname)].agg({'CELL': np.sum}).all()>0:
            ax = plt.subplot(12, 11, plot_number,sharex=ax)
            plt.setp(ax, xticks=xtickss, xticklabels=xlabelss,visible=True)
            dff.loc[(dff['REGION']==rname)&(dff['CONF']==cname)].plot( x=['DATE'],y=['TILT_VALUE','CELL'], secondary_y='CELL',ax=ax,legend=True,grid=True,rot=90)
            ax.set_title(label=("%s-%s" % (rname,cname)))
            plot_number = plot_number + 1
with PdfPages('multipage4_pdf.pdf') as pdf:
    plt.tight_layout()
    pdf.savefig()
    plt.close()
```

There is only `xtickslabel` for subplots that below grid is empty, but I want it for all subplots.

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19626530/python-xticks-in-subplots) will help you. If you don't find a solution, please, provide a sample of `dff` in order to reproduce your example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python xticks in subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19626530/python-xticks-in-subplots)

Comment: @Sheldore Same link as the one I mentionned...

Comment: dff
DATE REGION CONF CELL TILT_VALUE
Oca.14 abcdd 1L2L4L 141 51
Oca.14 abcdd 1L3L 14 58
Oca.14 abcdd 1L6L 6 58
Oca.14 abcdd 6L 86 48
Oca.14 cdfgvh 1L 682 62
Oca.14 cdfgvh 1L3L 58 64
Oca.14 cdfgvh 1L6L 2 60
Oca.14 cdfgvh 2L 147 46
Oca.14 cdfgvh 2L3L 98 42
Oca.14 cdfgvh 2L3L4L 48 49
Oca.14 cdfgvh 6L 45 30
Oca.14 tghyuj 1L6L 64 38
Oca.14 tghyuj 2L 31 47
6.Kas olsde 1L2L3L 3381 68
6.Kas olsde 1L2L4L 66 56

Comment: Try putting the setting of the ticks and labels *after* the plotting command. Else, please do read [mcve] and make sure the code in your question is runnable.

Comment: I could not upload picture of dff structure or sample of data in proper format. AS I wrote above dff is consist of 5 columns, DATE, REGION, CONF, CELL and TILT_VALUE. REGION has 12 different values and conf has 11 different values. CELL is integer and TILT_VALUE is float.I tried to plot 11x12 subplots grouped by REGION and CONF to show cell and TILT_VALUE. I plotted correctly. I try to show xticks for each plot but could not.