# automatic legend in python plot and limitation of axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am plotting the results using the following code.

Is there any way to add legend Automatically? I mean if `z=1,9` the plot automatically write  the legend of each line that this color is for `z=1` and that one for `z=2`

and another one how to increase the sections of each axis? not their limits, just their sections. here I just see `0, 0.5, 1`, but I want to have `0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3,...`

```
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3)
while True:
        inp  = float(input("PLEASE ENTER VALUE:"))
        if inp==0:
            print('***')
            print('0 Is not acceptable')
            print('***')
        else:
            for mg in np.arange(100,3000,500):
                for z in np.arange(0,1):
                    for test in range(0,1):
                        Ju_list=[]
                        ET_list=[]
                        ETmgncmb_list=[]
                        ETmgcmb_list=[]
                        nu_list=[]

                        for xx in range(1,819):
                            Ju = dfimppara.iloc[xx, 1]
                            Jl = dfimppara.iloc[xx, 2]
                            lim = Ju - Jl
                            if inp<0:
                                if lim > 1:
                                    pass
                                else:
                                    Ju_list.append(dfimppara.iloc[xx, 1])
                                    ET_list.append(ET(xx, 0,0,100))
                                    ETmgncmb_list.append(ET(xx, 0,0,mg))
                                    ETmgcmb_list.append(ET(xx, 0,1,mg))

                                    ax1.plot(Ju_list, ET_list)
                                    ax2.plot(Ju_list, ETmgncmb_list)
                                    ax3.plot(Ju_list, ETmgcmb_list)



                            else: 
                                ... some lines of code

            break

ax1.title.set_text('T_ex vs. J'  )
ax2.title.set_text('T_ex vs. J'  )
ax3.title.set_text('T_ex vs. J ')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so you can set the places of your tick marks yourself, just by using:

```py
plt.sca(axes[0, 0])  #here you specify for what subplot you want to change the xticks
plt.xticks(np.arange(0,1.1,0.1))
```

More information on that topic you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19626530/python-xticks-in-subplots)

if you want to have a legend you can just add a label to your plots and then call the legend with it's position:

```py
ax1.plot(Ju_list, ET_list, label='ET_list')
ax2.plot(Ju_list, ETmgncmb_list, label='ETmgncmb_list')
ax3.plot(Ju_list, ETmgcmb_list, label='ETmgcmb_list')

ax1.legend(loc='best')
ax2.legend(loc='best')
ax3.legend(loc='best')
```

Comment: I tried it before, here I see too many problems that I could not manage to find a solution. the first one is, in this legend, we should have exactly these ones`z=0, and `z=1`. but here I have 10000 `'ET_list'` in the figure because we are in 3 `for loop` s. and apart from this problem that there is too many 'ET_list', their name should be change for each line

Comment: Well, how many curves are you plotting? Of course if you plot 10000 curves with the same label, it will occur 10000 times. I mean you can alter the label in each loop with regular string operations. Also how do you want to label 10000 curves with individual labels and at the same time they are supposed to have only 2 labels?

Comment: there are not 1000 curves. there are many loops but each one affects just one fucntion. as you see I have 3 for loops but just for example `mg` is variable.

Comment: Well, the thing is you call your plot a bunch of times so you are plotting a lot of curves. That is the exact reason why you have more than just one `ET_list` in the figure. If you don't believe me you can just place a `print` in front of your plotting call and you will see that for each `ET_list` in your plot you will also get a print.