# When I set different xticklabels for different subplots in a multiplot figure, only the last one is used

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to create a multiplot figure with two different sets of xticklabels.  When I use this MWE,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

arr1 = np.random.random((3,3))
arr2 = np.random.random((3,3))
arr3 = np.random.random((3,3))
arr4 = np.random.random((3,3))

set1_labels = ['Label1', 'Label2', 'Label3']
set2_labels = ['Label4', 'Label5', 'Label6']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2,ncols=2, sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=(18,8))

ax[0,0].plot(arr1.T,lw=3)
ax[0,1].plot(arr3.T,lw=3)

ax[1,0].plot(arr2.T,lw=3)
ax[1,0].set_xticks([0,1,2])
ax[1,0].set_xticklabels(set1_labels)

[a,b,c] = ax[1,1].plot(arr4.T,lw=3)
ax[1,1].legend([a,b,c],['a','b','c'], prop={'size':16})
ax[1,1].set_xticks([0,1,2])
ax[1,1].set_xticklabels(set2_labels)

fig.tight_layout()

plt.savefig('mwe.png')
plt.show()
```

I get:

[image]

Only set2_labels appear at the bottom of the columns, I want the highlighted labels to say "Label1", "Label2" and "Label3".  I have also tried to use the approach given at https://stackoverflow.com/a/19626667/3662581 and I got the same result.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `sharex=True` to `sharex='col'`, as suggested in the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html):

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2,ncols=2, sharex='col', sharey='all', figsize=(18,8))
```

Here the result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `sharex` option in `subplots`:

```
#this:
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2,ncols=2, sharey=True, figsize=(18,8))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: But then the top row of subplots doesn't have the same xticks as the bottom row.

Comment: @BigBen I guess then OP can insert `set_xticks` for each subplot individually, not just the bottom ones :-).